# HDMI to DisplayPort adapter

Tags: displayport

Is it possible that this adapter:

[image]

CAN'T transfer the video from HDMI port on my laptop to DisplayPort on the monitor like this?

[image]

https://www.amazon.de/Icy-Box-IB-AC508-DisplayPort-3840x2160/dp/B00KIRY8GC/ref=sr_1_9?s=computers&ie=UTF8&qid=1494767338&sr=1-9&keywords=icy+box+dp+adapter

Comment: While it is possible, it would depend on the individual adapter if it was defective. Do you have one that isn't working?

Comment: I just bought one and I have a Laptop with HDMI and a monitor with DisplayPort input....and there is no image on the monitor! It seems like this works only in one direction DisplayPort to HDMI and not the other way around!

Comment: May sound stupid, but is the monitor plugged in/turned on?

Comment: Of course...I have a Dell U2312HM and all is set properly

Comment: What operating system are you running on the lap top?

Comment: Windows 7, and i have one more with Ubuntu....So I have tried both of them and it wont work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58747/discussion-between-lewis4u-and-k-a).

Comment: I would actually expect this to *not* work. DisplayPort output is backwards compatible to HDMI, but HDMI is not forwards compatible to DisplayPort.  Your adaptor is in the wrong direction for the connection to work and you probably need an active adaptor. https://www.amazon.co.uk/StarTech-HDMI-DisplayPort-Active-Converter/dp/B004I6IYSM

Comment: Yes. I have already figured it out and made an answer to it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Setup = Laptop HDMI out --> HDMI to HDMI cable --> HDMI to DP adapter --> Monitor DP in = Doesn't Work!

The computer HDMI cannot send a signal to a monitor DP. Computer DP can always send a signal to a monitor HDMI. That is why you see so many DP to HDMI cables. To do computer HDMI to monitor DP, you would have to invest in one of these converters: https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16815158264

source: http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/peripherals/f/3529/t/19567621

Answer (score 1):

Probably it is a displayport-hdmi conversion cable. It works only in one direction so not from your laptop/computer to the external screen, although the connections do fit. The problem is that the converter works not to the other direction. Then you need another cable whitch is a lot more expensive (about 50-60 Euro).