# Can I covert HDMI output to DisplayPort, after converting DisplayPort to HDMI

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi, displayport

I'm aware that we can not convert HDMI signal to DisplayPort without using an active converter, as covered [here and other similar questions](https://superuser.com/questions/1209073/hdmi-to-displayport-adapter)

However I'm asking about a special case, where the HDMI source is converted from DisplayPort itself, e.g from a [USB-C dock](https://www.lenovo.com/us/en/accessories-and-monitors/docking/universal-cable-docks-usb/Lenovo-USB-C-Mini-Dock-US/p/40AU0065US). Can I use a passive cable to revert the HDMI output back to DisplayPort?

Background:

I'm asking this because I had some bad experience of HDMI compatibility issues on Linux. Basically the monitor side would mis-report EDID as supporting YCbCr/FullRGB/LimitedRGB and the GPU driver believes it but it may or may not work. On Windows this is not a huge deal because all GPU driver control panel can force a format but on Linux there's no such interface ([AMDGPU is in progress](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/drm/amd/-/issues/476) while [for Intel/X use xrandr](https://forum.kodi.tv/showthread.php?tid=279014), which is not supported by Intel/Wayland).

Using DVI or DisplayPort makes it much easier as they inherently doesn't support LimitedRGB and YCbCr so there's no ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I use a passive cable to revert the HDMI output back to DisplayPort?

Your USB-C dock or the laptop itself effectively is an active converter from DP to HDMI.
(Likely via [DP++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayPort#DisplayPort_dual-mode_(DP++)))
This means the HDMI port is outputting a normal HDMI signal with no passive compatibility for DisplayPort.

You may have a display that implements DP++ on the input. Which means it could accept HDMI signals over a DisplayPort connector, but this is **very** uncommmon.

Anything that is passively converting between DP and HDMI connectors is going to be carrying a normal HDMI signal; Which means the color mode information could still be transported and this would not solve your problem.